# Recuperar valor se nulo no Flutter SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou aprendendo flutter por esses dias.

Estou estudando Shared Preferences:

Quando salvo no Shared Preferences e recupero a informação, funciona, mas quando removo e tento recuperar a informação, gostaria que mostrasse o texto "Sem valor". Mas dá erro no app

Segue parte do código e suas funções

```
  TextEditingController _controllerCampo = TextEditingController();
  String _textoSalvo = "Nada salvo!";

  _salvar() async{

    String valorDigitado = _controllerCampo.text;

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("nome", valorDigitado);
    print("operacao (salvar) $valorDigitado");
  }
  _recuperar() async {

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _textoSalvo = prefs.getString("nome") ?? "Sem valor";
    });

  }

  _remover() async{
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.remove("nome");
      setState(() {
        _textoSalvo = "";
      });
  }
```

Justamente aqui

```
_textoSalvo = prefs.getString("nome") ?? "Sem valor";
```

Aqui está o trecho para adicionar o texto e os botões

```
     TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Digite algo"
              ),
              controller: _controllerCampo,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Salvar",
                     style: TextStyle(
                       fontSize: 15
                     ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: _salvar,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Recuperar",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: _recuperar,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Remover",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: _remover,
                )
```

Dá esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Favor inserir o código completo. Principalmente a parte do Text que você cria com o `_textoSalvo`. O erro não está nisso que você mostrou.

Comment: Adicionei o outros métodos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro não está neste método que você está mostrando. Portanto, é necessário o código completo para análise.

Como `_recuperar()` é assíncrono, muito provavelmente o `_textoSalvo` está nulo ao executar o build e renderizar a tela, o que ocasiona o erro.
Afinal, o *future* será completado com o resultado apenas no próximo *event loop* da *isolate*.

Para testar, mude seu `Text` para `Text(_textoSalvo ?? 'teste')` e o erro deve sumir.

Comment: Adicionei os outros métodos na pergunta

Comment: Realmente. Parei o app, reiniciei o pc, testei e funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Testa se existe a chave antes:

```
_recuperar() async {

final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
if (prefs.containsKey("nome"))
{
    setState(() 
    { 
       _textoSalvo = prefs.getString("nome"); 
    });
} 

}
```